# Apple style "Waiting" animation for D7 needed

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know an Apple style "waiting" animation VCL component for using with Delphi 7? Thanks

Comment: I think you should make your own. That usually makes the most professional look at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know about the current Apple look, but a free online service to create Ajax loading gif files is here:

http://www.ajaxload.info/

> Create easily your own ajax loader
>   icon :
>
> 1. Select the type of indicator you want
> 2. Enter the background code color you want
>        (tick "Transparent background" if you don't want one
> 3. Enter the foreground code color you want
>
> Press "Generate it"

Comment: If you convert the gif to an ani file you can also use TAnimation to display the wait animation.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this thing (circular progress animation)?
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/acp.asp
TMS has one.