# Waiting animation with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to implement a wating animation of the kind mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936720), particularly something that looks like this:

[image]

But I do not want to use graphic files, and am trying to implement it purely in html5 canvas  and javascript. Also, I want a circular black background rather than a square one. As a first step, I tried to draw a static frame (without any movement/rotation) and did this:

```
<html>
<head><script>
window.onload = function(){
    var c=document.getElementById("waiting").getContext("2d");
    c.lineCap="round";
    c.fillStyle="#353535";
    c.translate(100,100);
    function slit(p){
        shade = 256*p;
        th = 2*Math.PI*p;
        cos = Math.cos(th);
        sin = Math.sin(th);
        c.strokeStyle = '#'+((shade<<16)+(shade<<8)+shade).toString(16);
        c.moveTo(55*cos, 55*sin);
        c.lineTo(84*cos, 84*sin);
        c.stroke();
        c.closePath();
    }
    c.lineWidth=0;
    c.arc(0,0,100,0,Math.PI*2);
    c.fill();
    c.lineWidth=7;
    for(var i = 0;i<1;i+=0.05){slit(i);}
}
</script></head>
<body><canvas id="waiting" width=200 height=200></canvas></body>
</html>
```

The result I get is:

[image]

The problem is that, the `lineCap="round"` is not working correctly for all of the "slits", and the `lineWidth=0` attribute is not working for the edge of the circle. What am I doing wrong? I checked it with  Chrome 16.0.912.63 and Firefox 10.0, and got similar results.

---

For the next step, I am going to let parts of the functions that I created above interact with

```
window.animationFrames = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);};
 })();
```

but for the time being, I need to solve this problem first.

Comment: here is a jQuery plugin for doing the same thing: http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/, but you want to do this as a learning experience then that's cool

Comment: @asawilliams I see. Thanks for the link. I did not want to rely on external libraries, but I will take a look at it. Maybe I can extract and study the relevant parts of it. But still, I want to know why my code above does not work as intended.

Comment: @asawilliams The implementation that you linked seems to work without jQuery. I will look at it deeper.

Comment: fwiw, the link provided by @asawilliams doesn't require jQuery or Zepto, but it supports them if they are present by creating plugins. there is, however, a core API that is available if you don't want the dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion here.

Zero is not an acceptable value for line width. The spec dictates that if you say `lineWidth = 0` that it will be a no-op.

Furthermore you are not using `lineWidth` there because you are not stroking. `fill()` does not take line width into account.

As for the other issue, all you have to do is call `beginPath`! See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JfcDL/

Just adding the `beginPath` call and you'll get this with your code:

[image]

What you were doing incorrectly was drawing the entire path so far with every new `stroke()`. You need to call `beginPath` to open a new one so that the `stroke` only applies to the last part and not all the parts made so far.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help by the several people here, I finally came up with this code, which works fully with the movement:

```
<html>
<head><script>
var r1 =  400;
var r2 =  340;
var r3 = 220;
var slitWidth = 40;
var speed = 0.0004;
var attenuation = 1.7;

function rgbToHex(r, g, b){
    return '#' + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}

window.nextFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);};
})();

window.onload = function(){
    var waiting=document.getElementById('waiting').getContext('2d');
    function slit(d,p){
        shade = Math.round(Math.pow(1-(d+p)%1, attenuation)*255)
        th = Math.PI*2*(p);
        cos = Math.cos(th);
        sin = Math.sin(th);
        waiting.strokeStyle = rgbToHex(shade, shade, shade);
        waiting.beginPath();
        waiting.moveTo(r2*cos, r2*sin);
        waiting.lineTo(r3*cos, r3*sin);
        waiting.stroke();
        waiting.closePath();
    }
    function frame(){
        waiting.arc(0,0,r1,0,Math.PI*2);
        waiting.fill();
        var time = new Date().getTime()* speed;
        for(var p = 1;p>0;p-=0.05){slit(time,p);}
        nextFrame(function(){frame();});
    }
    waiting.lineCap='round';
    waiting.lineWidth=slitWidth;
    waiting.fillStyle='#353535';
    waiting.translate(r1, r1);
    frame();
}
</script></head>
<body><canvas id='waiting' width=800 height=800></canvas></body>
</html>
```